# Drawing a random number from set of numbers excluding those given in certain sets

Tags: python, numpy

Suppose I have a two arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
```

I want to generate another length-10 array whose i-th entry is a random integer drawn from the set (`{0...9}` **minus** the elements `a[i]` and `b[i]`).

Being a relative rookie when it comes to NumPy, I thought the easiest way to do this might be:

1. obtain the set difference `x = {0...9} - (a[i] union b[i])` for each `i`
2. do `np.random.choice(x[i], 1)` for each `i`

But I'm finding this a little tricky because I can't figure out how to map `setdiff1d` elementwise across 2 arrays. Is there an obvious way to do this in NumPy (i.e. ideally without having to resort to Python sets etc.)?

Comment: `import random
random.sample(set(range(0, 10)).difference([a[i], b[i]]), 1)[0]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way:

```
In [87]: col = np.array((a, b)).T # Or as a better way np.column_stack((a,b)); suggested by @Divakar

In [88]: r = np.arange(10)

In [89]: np.ravel([np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(r, i), 1) for i in col])
Out[89]: array([7, 8, 8, 6, 6, 8, 6, 5, 5, 6])
```

Or as a numpytonic approach:

```
In [101]: def func(x):                           
             return np.random.choice(np.setdiff1d(r, x), 1)
   .....: 

In [102]: np.apply_along_axis(func, 1, col).ravel()
Out[102]: array([6, 7, 9, 6, 4, 6, 7, 4, 0, 7])
```

Comment: +1 loading the vectors into a matrix and transposing to get the right shape. very NumPy-thonic, one might say!

Comment: Maybe use `np.column_stack((a,b))`? Also, I wouldn't suggest `np.apply_along_axis` for performance, which I think NumPy is usually meant for.

Comment: @Divakar Indeed that'd be a better way. Regarding the `apply_along_axis`  I never had any benchmark, but I think list comprehension is faster.

Comment: Agreed! In fact recently I had the privilege to [benchmark those](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39309371/3293881) and I think `apply_along_axis` was way slower than even the naive loop. So, I am guessing loop comprehension could be preferred too.

Comment: @Divakar I think the essence of `apply_along_axis`  is for situations that we    are doing a lot of calculations and specially with large data sets. For such snippets the cost of converting the data to numpy objects is very costly to the performance that we gain.

Comment: Hmm could be. At least from that benchmark I could conclude that for compute heavy problems, I would stick to loop compr. or just naive loops if ufuncs directly aren't applicable. For other problems, I will test out it I guess in future as they show up.

Answer (score 0):

The `np.random.choice` function seems to not allow to operate on several sets at once.  Thus, you will need some form of loop to make the separate calls to `np.random.choice` for each element of the output.  Given that a loop is needed, I don't think one can do much better than your suggestion in the question.  The following code implements your idea and hides the required loop a bit by using a list comprehension:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
b = np.random.randint(0,10,10)
domain = set(range(10))
res = [ np.random.choice(list(domain - set(avoid))) for avoid in zip(a, b) ]
res = np.array(res)
```